# Facebook Graph Api Throws "No Node Specified" When Requesting Profile Picture Of App Users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am using authentication with facebook and getting basic user information (id, fullname, gender) for my app.

As far as I understand, as part of an API upgrade on Facebook, they are now issuing app-scoped user ids (each user has a unique id for each app).

I am trying to fetch the profile picture using the path "https://graph.facebook.com/{app-scoped-user-id}/picture

The really weird thing is that it works for some users, but for others it throws an OauthException "No Node Specified"

What could it be? I also tried using different GET parameters like (redirect=false) but with no success.

Thanks.

Comment: The implication is whatever variable you're calling {app-scoped-user-id} in your example is null or empty when the request makes it to Facebook's side - is that likely based on your code?

Comment: This makes sense. However, I am manually putting the request in the url with the full id, and it still throws the exception.

Comment: Where are you getting the IDs from? Is it possible the user (whose picture you're trying to fetch) blocked your app subsequent to your fetching their ID, or something like that?

Comment: I am storing the Ids in MYSQL and I made sure that mysql stores the whole string. I am quiet sure the user has not blocked me. It is really weird.